# What IR receivers would work on a 2010 MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, remote-control

If you didn't already know, the 2010 MacBook Air doesn't have an IR receiver.

Does anyone know of a very small and cheap IR receiver that would work with a MacBook Air and the Apple Remote?

Here are a couple of examples, do you know if they work?

1. [Micro Mini USB to Infrared IrDA Wireless Port Dongle Adapter Receiver PC](http://bestofferbuy.com/Micro-Mini-USB-to-Infrared-IrDA-Wireless-Port-Dongle-Adapter-Receiver-PC-p-32145.html)
2. [Syba SD-U1IRDA-NM USB Fast Infra-Red Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JPGQ4U)

Also, are there any good bluetooth remotes that work similarly to the Apple IR remote, and have similar design quality and size?

Comment: Neil, could you, please. tell us what range you can get with Apple Remote and any of these USB IrDA adapters? Did you have to do anything to configure them? What software do you use? Could you, please, describe how you got it to work? Unfortunately, information on this topic is really scarce. Your update could be very valuable to StackExchange communities. (Dear moderators feel free to purge this misplaced question of mine as soon as Neil responds.)

Answer (score 3):

For IR, it sounds like you want [Twisted Melon's Manta TR1](http://twistedmelon.com/mira/hardware.html) ($20).

As far as a Bluetooth remote goes, it depends on what you want to do with the remote. If all that matters to you is cheap, take a look at the [Targus Bluetooth Laser Presentation Remote](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HQDFGC) (~$20).

Comment: I actually bought two of these IR receivers, and they work great. They're also supposed to work in Linux, but as usual, it's a pain in the ass to get working.